# SQL server ODBC connection for Active Directory user who doesn't log in to the windows

Tags: sql-server-2008, active-directory, odbc

Do you think it is possible to create a SQL server ODBC Connection for an active directory user who doesn't log in into the windows.

Ideally this type of users will be used in the batch process. So, Another person logs in and creates a batch process and runs it with another user.

Note: I dont want to create a SQL server authentication. Instead would like to use active directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to [impersonate a Windows account when connecting to SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+impersonate+windows+account)

Comment: What do you mean by impersonatae?

Comment: I mean one account [acting with the permissions of a second account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391(v=vs.85).aspx). I was guessing that "runs it with another user" means "runs it *as* another user" but I may be wrong.

Comment: No. I don't think I want to impersonate. My question is more of related to ODBC connection. I wanted to know whether I can create an ODBC connection without windows authentication and SQL server authentication.

Comment: What does that mean? You must authenticate the connection, either with Windows or SQL authentication. ODBC supports either, just use the appropriate [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#sql-server-native-client-10-0-odbc-driver).

Answer (score 0):

You can't save alternate windows authentication credentials into an ODBC connection for SQL Server. You can only save credentials into the ODBC setting if you use SQL Server authentication.

There are other options though.

You can create a windows authentication ODBC connection to SQL server even if the account you create the connection with doesn't have database access. You just have to untick the "Connect to SQL Server to obtain default settings for the additional configuration options" and you can't use the "Test connection" feature. You just have to create the connection on faith.

With that connection, it will only work if your batch process or application is running as a different account to the logged-in user. Services that run as system accounts do this sort of thing. If you create an application that can be run as a service then you can change the account it runs under.

You can also run as another account manually. Using explorer you can [shift] + right-click on an application and choose "Run As different user" and then enter the other account credentials. Then when the process or application uses the ODBC connection, it will be the correct credentials and work.

There's also "ShellRunAs" https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/shellrunas.aspx

Comment: If I create user with "run as a different user" will this connection stay on, or will it expire after some time?

Comment: @Pomme That's worth trying. I assume that if the connection times out or closes that you would have to run as another user again so would be tricky to automate. Better to use windows authentication for real people and SQL Auth for services, or perhaps a service account in Azure AD if using that.